# How to list all MBeans using JMX client

Tags: java, linux, jmx, mbeans

I am trying to list all published applications using JMX client 'jconsole' but nothing seems to be happening as the screen stays on that console. Is there a command to use to list all published applications?

Comment: What does “the screen stays on that console” mean?

Comment: when you type in 'jconsole', it appears its trying to do something but nothing happens

Comment: Unlike its name suggest `jconsole` is a GUI program opening its own window which won’t print anything to the console.

Answer (score 1):

It appeared my Java installation was corrupt so had to re-install it. Now its responding and loading up. I am now able to connect and view the MBeans.

Also running the following commands from remote Linux machine also worked:

```
java -jar jmxterm-1.0-alpha-4-uber.jar -l <remote server name>:<port>
```

Then type `domains` from the prompt to get the MBeans lists, then type `beans` to get the corresponding domain type.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest tool is the `jps` command included in the jdk. It just lists the running JVMs. When listing all local applications, it’s not for sure whether a JMX tool can establish a JMX connection to all of the JVMs from this list. The bigger problem is that this list will be exactly the same as jconsole provides you and since I don’t understand your problem description I don’t know whether `jps` will help you.